# Scaling down the SPI0 clock value on RPi 3B+/4B

Tags: pi-4, pi-3b+, spi, system-clock

I have a custom STM32 MCU board that interfaces with an RPi 3B+ via the SPI protocol. The MCU (STM32F407) has its SPI peripheral clock set at 84MHz and is configured as a slave device. For reliable transmission, the Master (in this case, the RPi) needs to have its SPI clock at 1/2 value i.e, at 24MHz or lower (I read that it needs to be an even number). From what I understand the RPi's SPI clock runs at 250MHz. How can I scale down this clock value?

Answer (score 0):

Anyway you want.

Most people would either use the Linux SPI driver which lets you set the SPI bits per second or a library which lets you set the SPI bits per second.

E.g.

[lg library lgSpiOpen](http://abyz.me.uk/lg/lgpio.html#lgSpiOpen)

[pigpio library spiOpen](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/cif.html#spiOpen)

Comment: You mean the `spidev`? Do you have any links you can point me to?